# Proof of injections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $f: X\to Y$ be a surjection and $g: Y\to Z$ be such that $g \circ f$ is an injection. Prove that both $f$ and $g$ are injections.

My attempt:

Since $f$ is surjective then there exists $ x, x'\in X$ such that $(x,y)\in f$ and $(x',y')\in f$, but since $g\circ f$ is an injection then $(x,z)\in g\circ f$ and $(x',z)\in g\circ f$ which implies that $x=x'$ ... but now I am stuck completing the proof.

Comment: Why would someone vote to close this and how is this too localized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.

Suppose $g(y_1)=g(y_2)$ and by surjectivity of $f$, find $x_1,x_2\in X$ with $f(x_1)=y_1$ and $f(x_2)=y_2$.  Then we have $g\circ f(x_1)=g\circ f(x_2)$ which implies that $x_1=x_2$, which in turn implies that $y_1=y_2$ so that $g$ is injective.

Next, suppose $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.  Apply $g$ and use the injectivity of $g\circ f$ to conclude that $f$ is injective.

Comment: Why does your first paragraph conclude that $g$ is injective instead of $f$?

Comment: $g$ is injective if the equality $g(y_1)=g(y_2)$ implies the equality $y_1=y_2$.  I began the first paragraph with the assumption that $g(y_1)=g(y_2)$, and showed that this led to the conclusion that $y_1=y_2$.

Comment: Ah, of course you did. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

For any functions $f: X \rightarrow Y$, $g: Y \rightarrow Z$, $g \circ f$ is an injection implies that $f$ is an injection. In your case $f$ is also surjective, hence bijective. Then, writing $g = (g \circ f) \circ f^{-1}$ what can you conclude?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$. Then $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$ so $x=y$. Hence $f$ is an injection.

Suppose $g(x)=g(y)$. Then there exist $x_0,y_0\in X$ such that $f(x_0)=x$ and $f(y_0)=y$. It follows that $g(f(x_0))=g(f(y_0))$ so $x_0=y_0$. But now $x=y$ so $g$ is an injection.